# Is it wrong to close around classes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Poking through The Guardian's [Scribe](https://github.com/guardian/scribe) Javascript library, I noticed they're using a pattern where they close around classes.

I haven't seen this done before, so I'm hoping to learn something from it.

Here's a simplified example illustrating the pattern:

```
define(function () {

  return function (scribe) {
    function CommandPatch(commandName) {
      this.commandName = commandName;
    }

    CommandPatch.prototype.queryState = function (value) {
      scribe.something();
    };

    return CommandPatch;
  };

});
```

Here, the exported function generates a new class (prototype) on every call, each bound to a different instance of `scribe`.

If I were to follow this pattern in Typescript, I might do this:

```
export = function (scribe: Scribe) {
    return class CommandPatch {
        private commandName: string

        constructor (commandName: string) {
            this.commandName = commandName
        }

        queryState() {
            scribe.something();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that this may not be a very good pattern?

Can this pattern cause memory leaks?

Why are they doing it this way? Just to avoid typing out `this.scribe`?

If I were to follow a more traditional OO pattern, I might do this:

```
export class CommandPatch {
    private scribe: Scribe
    private commandName: string

    constructor (scribe: Scribe, commandName: string) {
        this.commandName = commandName
        this.scribe = scribe
    }

    queryState() {
        this.scribe.something();
    }
}
```

This way, only one prototype gets created for the same class, rather than generating a new prototype for every instance of `Scribe`.

Is this any better or worse?

Am I saving any memory or CPU overhead or anything else worthwhile?

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong, but it is not needed. Those patterns are usually used so you don't pollute the global scope.

In ES6 each file is a module, and only what you **export** explicitly will be available to the outside. Anything else defined in that file is available only in that file and does not pollute the global scope.

Also as Slava pointed out, TypeScript will do it for you when transpiling to ES5 or lower.

Comment: My concern here is that `Scribe` internally keeps a list of `CommandPatch` instances - if the `CommandPatch` instance keeps a reference to it's owner `Scribe` instance, can either of those ever get deallocated from memory? If `CommandPatch` has a `this.scribe` property, at least `Scribe` could signal it to delete it's owner reference when `Scribe` gets destroyed - if instead `CommandPatch` closes around a variable `scribe`, is JS clever enough to somehow deallocate everything when the owner `Scribe` instance falls out of scope?

Answer (score 1):

If you go here: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20AModule%20%7B%0A%09class%20A%20%7B%0A%09public%20foo%20()%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%7D), you can see that typescript actually doing the same pattern when transpiling to javascript, so no need for it in Typescript

Update:
Or using the export method of defining modules: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20%09class%20A%20%7B%0A%09public%20foo%20()%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)